# Como implementar um chat numa aplicação Android com backend WebApi

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api

Estou a desenvolver uma aplicação Android que consome serviços de um projeto WebApi. Em uma parte desta aplicação será necessário o desenvolvimento de chat entre duas ou mais pessoas.

Diante deste cenário, qual a melhor abordagem para desenvolver um chat sem utilizar um framework de terceiro? As mensagens devem passar pelo backend WebAPI e serem notificadas como evento, ou a comunicação deve ser direta entre os dispositivos Android?

Comment: Veja se isto ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24359453/how-do-asp-net-backend-and-web-api-web-service-hosted-on-azure-send-push-notific?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma alternativa para o uso do `GCM` respondida por @GustavoBitencourt, é utilizar [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) para a comunicação entre o WebApi e o Android.

Na página de tutoriais do [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) você pode utilizar o mesmo exemplo de chat para utilizar no android, implementando a lógica de `Javascript` no Android utilizando o [SignalR Client para Java/Android](https://github.com/SignalR/java-client)

Você pode seguir esses passos para fazer um teste de chat:

**Implementar um Hub na sua solução web**

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
namespace SignalRChat
{
    //Nome que será utilizado para criação do hub no cliente
    [HubName("chatHub")]
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        //Método utilizado para enviar a mensagem para o cliente
        [HubMethodName("send")]
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            // Método que será chamado no cliente.
            // Esse método precisa ser implementado no Android.
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
        }
    }
}
```

**Implementar o cliente no Android para receber as mensagens**

<sub>(nesse exemplo, o cliente foi implementado num Android Service)</sub>

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Logger logger = new Logger() {
            @Override
            public void log(String message, LogLevel level) {
                Log.d("SignalR-Test", level.toString() + ":" + message);
            }
        };

    HubConnection connection = new HubConnection(server,queryStringQualquer,true, logger);

    HubProxy proxy = connection.createHubProxy("chatHub");

    //Foi utilizado o tipo de transporte LongPolling, mas pode ser modificado
    //pra o transport de sua preferência.
     SignalRFuture<Void> awaitConnection = connection.start(new LongPollingTransport(logger));

     try {
        awaitConnection.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    proxy.on( "broadcastMessage", new SubscriptionHandler2<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public void run(String nome, String msg) {
            //Aqui a mensagem é recebida e você exibe ela da forma que preferir                
        }
    }, String.class, String.class);
}
```

**Exemplo de como enviar mensagem para o Hub**

```
proxy.invoke("send","Malloni","Olá, tudo bem?");
```

---

**Notas**

É bastante simples de se implementar e evita depender do GCM para a entrega das mensagens, já que ele não garante que sua mensagem chegue na hora.

Você terá o controle de tudo!

Answer (score 4):

Recomendo estes artigos para responder uma questão:

http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample
http://www.appsrox.com/android/tutorials/instachat/
https://github.com/Pirngruber/AndroidIM

Um chat aparentemente, não me parece ser complexo, pois pelo entender consiste em um serviço de mensageria de mão dupla.
Sobre o uso do WebApi, creio que será tranquilo, pois ele é apenas serviços REST, ao qual o Android consegue trabalhar muito bem. Nessa função de comunicação com servidor, recomendo ver essa API:
http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Sobre sua questão de as mensagens serem notificadas como evento, gostaria de acrescentar, que no meu ver, o correto seria você utilizar Google Cloud Messaging, por algumas questões, auxílio no menor consumo de bateria entre outros.
O GCM é bem tranquilo de se trabalhar com ele. Recomendo você dar uma olhada para ele fazer o serviço de mensageria/notificação, quando o usuário não estiver com o aplicativo aberto(em background).

Respondendo sua outra questão..

O GCM tem algumas funções/detalhes em relação a sua ideia como:
- receber uma notificação sem que precise ficar requisitando dados do servidor, ou seja, o servidor quando receber uma nova mensagem de um usuário, ele irá notificar o outro usuário do chat utilizando o GCM, não obrigando os usuários a ficarem com o app aberto.
- você irá precisar cadastrar os usuários no GCM, pois o GCM gera uma chave para cada usuário ao qual ele precisará para enviar a mensagem. Ou seja, a comunicação aqui não será cliente-servidor, mas sim, o inverso que é servidor-cliente.
- as mensagens enviadas pelos servidores não podem exceder de 4kb. Isso para você terá duas funcionalidades que são: 
1) Como o chat normalmente consiste em texto, talvez 4kb seja o suficiente para você;
2) Mas caso não seja, você deverá implementar o fluxo que o pessoal geralmente usa da função do GCM, que é receber a notificação, ao qual terá um broadcastreceiver esperando a notificação, e quando recebido, irá no seu servidor buscar todo o texto que o usuário digitou.

Você comentou o seguinte: "o usuário envia um post para o WebApi que armazena a informação da mensagem e cria um evento utilizando o GCM, que por sua vez notifica o segundo usuário que recebe a mensagem."
Sim, é basicamente isso, porém com mais um detalhe. Concorda que se ambos usuários do chat estiverem com o app aberto, não será necessário o uso de GCM, pois a conversa será em tempo real. Para isso, você deve implementar um mecanismo de status das conversas como o WhatsApp, que altera os ícones colocando um símbolo de OK quando foi visualizado. Ou seja, você pode fazer o seguinte mecanismo:
O usuário 1 envia mensagem, vai para o servidor e consequentemente irá aparecer para o usuário 2 caso ele tenha o app aberto, pois será enviado a mensagem para ele no chat. Faça um mecanismo ao qual você saberá se o usuário estará com o aplicativo ativo/aberto. Caso ele não esteja com o app aberto, faça com que o servidor saiba disso, e a mensagem que o outro usuário enviar, o servidor processe e envie por GCM.

Talvez tenha ficado um pouco embaraçoso o que tentei explicar, mas tente dar uma olhada nos links para ver se ajudar a esclarecer:

- https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html
- https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html
- https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html
- http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-ccs-with-xmpp/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ehbZjgJSAc

Comment: Gustavo. Você pode sugerir um fluxo para desenvolvimento desse mecanismo? Isto é, o usuário envia um post para o WebApi que armazena a informação da mensagem e cria um evento utilizando o GCM, que por sua vez notifica o segundo usuário que recebe a mensagem. É realmente isso?